# Handling exception at application level

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net main desktop application and there are also supporting applications of the main application.

I have to do exception handling for all the methods in the application but don't want to put try catch in each and every method or event click.

Is there any centralized way of exception handling.

Secondly, can i avoid any excepttion and keep the application running without any crash.
I mean instead of crash can i display a yes/no message to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Main` sub-procedure, you can subscribe to the `Application.ThreadException` event and force all other non-thread UI exceptions to a handler, like this:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    ' Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions 
    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf HandleThreadException

    ' Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go 
    ' through our handler
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)

    ' Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions  
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf HandleUnhandledException

    ' Runs the application.
    Application.Run(New YourForm())
End Sub

' Handle the UI exceptions by showing a dialog box, and asking the user whether 
' or not they wish to abort execution. 
Private Shared Sub Form1_UIThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal t As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
    Dim result As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult = _
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    Try
        result = ShowThreadExceptionDialog("Windows Forms Error", t.Exception)
    Catch 
        Try
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal Windows Forms Error", _
                    "Fatal Windows Forms Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        Finally
            Application.Exit()
        End Try 
    End Try 

    ' Exits the program when the user clicks Abort. 
    If result = DialogResult.Abort Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If 
End Sub 

' Handle the UI exceptions by showing a dialog box, and asking the user whether 
' or not they wish to abort execution  
Private Shared Sub CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Try 
        Dim ex As Exception = CType(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)
        Dim errorMsg As String = "An application error occurred. Please contact the adminstrator " & _
                "with the following information:" & ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf

        ' Since we can't prevent the app from terminating, log this to the event log. 
        If (Not EventLog.SourceExists("ThreadException")) Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("ThreadException", "Application")
        End If 

        ' Create an EventLog instance and assign its source. 
        Dim myLog As New EventLog()
        myLog.Source = "ThreadException"
        myLog.WriteEntry((errorMsg + ex.Message & ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & _
                "Stack Trace:" & ControlChars.Lf & ex.StackTrace))
    Catch exc As Exception
        Try
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal Non-UI Error", "Fatal Non-UI Error. Could not write the error to the event log. " & _
                    "Reason: " & exc.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        Finally
            Application.Exit()
        End Try 
    End Try 
End Sub 

' Creates the error message and displays it. 
Private Shared Function ShowThreadExceptionDialog(ByVal title As String, ByVal e As Exception) As DialogResult
    Dim errorMsg As String = "An application error occurred. Please contact the adminstrator " & _
     "with the following information:" & ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf
        errorMsg = errorMsg & e.Message & ControlChars.Lf & _
     ControlChars.Lf & "Stack Trace:" & ControlChars.Lf & e.StackTrace

    Return MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, title, MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
End Function
```

> Note: It is not a good idea to keep the program running when a fatal error happens that is caught at the root of the application, because the system may be in an invalid state and allowing the user to continue working may further corrupt the data in the system.

Comment: I don't have main method in mmy application. Iam new to windows application so is there any other place where i can put exception handling

Comment: Right-click on the Winform project, select application then click "View Application Events" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2bys999(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 4):

For your first question: 
    Yes, there is a centralized place to catch application level exception. Check application events:

```
Namespace My

' The following events are available for MyApplication:
' 
' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        ' Log it?
        ' handle it? 
    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

About your second question, there are couple of ways to keep your application running without crash:

1. catch the unhandled exception and just display a message
2. have a MDI parent window and catch exception at child forms
3. using services and handle the exception at service level
4. check the internet for more choices....